# Why Spark is not utilizing MongoDB replicaset?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have setup the same environment mentioned here, with the exception of keeping two MongoDB replicaset:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-pyspark-and-jupyter-notebook

But when I am doing a simple count(*) on a collection of million records , I don’t see Spark utilizing both MongoDB. I can see it going to the primary only.

I thought that Spark will utilize both nodes ?
What could I have missed here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs, I found out that dataframe partitions can't be distributed between replicaset members. However, each partition can be processed by a different spark worker.